# How is possible to create a python shell script like top unix command?

Tags: python, shell, cmd

I'm need to create a Python shell script that refresh output every n seconds like top unix command. 
what 's the best way to do this?

Comment: For a pure-python solution you'll probably want to use the [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) module.  I haven't used it myself but have heard that it's a bit complicated and tricky to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to write a script that prints your output (once), and then run your script using the [`watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command. The `watch` command will automatically clear the screen and run your script every few seconds (usually 2 by default).

If you really want to do this in pure Python, you can use the [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) module, or if you know your terminal is VT100-compatible you can go considerably simpler:

```
print "\x1b[H\x1b[2J",
print "hello clear world"
```

Comment: this command seems use a "fullscreen" shell, is not possible to implement this with python? (and relative clear method)...in this manner have the possibility to implement a cache system (my script is based to various REST API) without recall all every "refresh"

Comment: @Angelbit: I added a pure Python example.